# The random method in my Python library sometimes returns an error

Tags: python

I just got a raspberry pi and I was trying out a few of the *Python games* that came preinstalled with the raspbian OS.

I was playing *4 in a row* when at points it would suddenly quit. I launched the application through the terminal to find the error. This is what appears when the error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fourinarow.py", line 363, in <module>
    main()
  File "fourinarow.py", line 70, in main
    runGame(isFirstGame)
  File "fourinarow.py", line 104, in runGame
    column = getComputerMove(mainBoard)
  File "fourinarow.py", line 269, in getComputerMove
    return random.choice(bestMoves)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 275, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want to try fix the error so that it doesn't affect any programs that I design myself, but I'm also wondering if it's possible that this game uses the random module incorrectly?

Comment: without seeing the code nobody can do much for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are using the `random` module incorrectly.  Specifically, the variable `bestMoves` is an empty list.

Comment: @intboolstring: There is nothing more to say unless OP edits their code into the answer.  I mean, I could take ridiculous wild guesses, but they would probably be wrong.

Comment: @intboolstring: OP asked if they used the random module incorrectly.  They did, and I explained exactly how.  I answered their question.

Comment: @intboolstring: It's answered as best as it can be answered. The cause is identified; the OP can go from here to figure out why they're choosing from an empty `list`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10710537)

Comment: @skypjack: I refuse to repeat myself.  Read the comments above your own.

Answer (score -1):

The code is trying to access an item in the list `seq` that doesn't exist. In "fourinarow.py", line 269, in the definiton of `getComputerMove`, you could change:

```
return random.choice(bestMoves)
```

to

```
try:
    return random.choice(bestMoves)
except IndexError:
    return 'some default move'
```

Comment: That is stdlib code.  OP most likely did not write it.

Comment: I agree, thank you. If I knew what was going on I could suggest a better default value.

Comment: Not sure why all of the downvotes though... I think my answer is reasonable -- it's also not a problem with `random`, it's a problem with indexing an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: @rofls.  I believe your answer is well-written and deserves an up vote (I did up vote).

Comment: "Go patch the stdlib to return `'something else...'`" is not a reasonable answer unless the questioner is a Python developer.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with stdlib

Comment: Problem with the rasberry pi games? sure

Comment: Then why are you telling OP to change stdlib?

Comment: oh darn you're right... :/

Comment: @rofls: Yeah, but your answer is suggesting modifying the standard Python `random` module's code to avoid the issue. Which is not exactly productive.

Comment: Good call, thanks folks :)